# Magento2: What is the trigger after order created in Admin

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

So as we know the trigger for frontend was

```
checkout_onepage_controller_success_action
```

I have an order with specific custom options. Admin should be able to create orders from back-end and add this specific value for custom option to product on order. After payment created `(order created successfully)` I need to get the input option value of current products.

How do I implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you try the `adminhtml` event

```
checkout_submit_all_after
```

is dispatched in file

```
vendor\magento\module-sales\Model\AdminOrder\Create.php line 1917
```

and you can get the created order